# Columns are so narrow I can't edit

Tags: columns

First, I am not a coder. Why are the columns so narrow that I can't see enough to edit? I need to be able to link the text but can't see it to click on it. So frustrated.

Comment: You’ll need to provide a little more detail for anyone here to help you :)

Comment: Are you referring to a Columns block in the Block Editor?

Comment: could try zooming out in your browser?

Comment: yes using block editor. Need 5 columns. I am using the cover block. I can add the photo and text fine. I can only see the text alignment and change block type. I cannot see the link icon because the column is so narrow it gets cut off. Zooming in/out of the browser doesn't do anything to help.